# Why are symbols loading in VS2022 when I have symbol loading turned off?

Tags: visual-studio, symbols

I have symbols set to only load specified modules

[image: Only Specified Modules]

With no modules included

[image: No modules included]

And yet when I run the program in the IDE I see messages like

[image: loading symbols]

Comment: That's just not what the dialog does.  Unticking a server prevents it from being contacted when the debugger can't find a .pdb file.  Once it has one then it will use it regardless.  Deleting the .pdb from the cache directory is a workaround.

Comment: Is that the Empty Cache Symbol button? I notice that checking Enable Just My Code seems to have helped.